# perform additional match if the return node has a certain type

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've got a model that looks like this

[image]

I want to for a player to *recommend* a quest that would allow to complete his set of armor. I am doing this `cypher` query to return relationship `quest -> boots`.

```
MATCH (w:Armor)<-[:WEARS]-(p:Player)
MATCH (w)-[:PART_OF]->(set:ArmorSet)
MATCH (missing)-[:PART_OF]->(set)
MATCH (missing)<--(anything)
WHERE NOT (p)-[:WEARS]->(missing)
RETURN missing, anything
```

But how to adjust this query to return the `NPC` that gives the quest if `boots` is the reward of the quest? Basically I want to check that if the node is of `quest` type, then I should return `npc` that gives that quest.

How to achieve that in Neo4j?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Original answer

### Creating your graph

For the ease of possible further answers and solutions I note my graph creating statement:

```
CREATE
  (player:Player {name: 'Player'}),
  (shield:Armor {name: 'Shield'}),
  (armor:Armor {name: 'Armor'}),
  (gauntlets:Armor {name: 'Gauntlets'}),
  (boots:Armor {name: 'Boots'}),
  (helmet:Armor {name: 'Helmet'}),
  (dragonSet:ArmorSet {name: 'Dragon Set'}),
  (quest1:Quest {name: 'Quest I'}),
  (quest2:Quest {name: 'Quest II'}),
  (npc1:Npc {name: 'NPC I'}),
  (npc2:Npc {name: 'NPC II'}),
  (player)-[:WEARS]->(shield)-[:PART_OF]->(dragonSet),
  (player)-[:WEARS]->(armor)-[:PART_OF]->(dragonSet),
  (player)-[:WEARS]->(gauntlets)-[:PART_OF]->(dragonSet),
  (npc1)-[:PROVIDES]->(quest1)-[:REWARDS]->(boots)-[:PART_OF]->(dragonSet),
  (npc2)-[:PROVIDES]->(quest2)-[:REWARDS]->(helmet)-[:PART_OF]->(dragonSet);
```

Line 2 to 12 creates the nodes, whereas line 13 to 17 establishes the relationships between them.

[image: graph2]

### Solution

```
MATCH
  (player:Player)-[:WEARS]->(armor:Armor)-[:PART_OF]->(dragonSet:ArmorSet),
  (missing)-[:PART_OF]->(dragonSet)
  WHERE NOT (player)-[:WEARS]->(missing:Armor)
WITH DISTINCT missing
MATCH (npc:Npc)-[:PROVIDES]->(quest:Quest)-[:REWARDS]->(missing)
RETURN npc.name AS npcName, quest.name AS questName, missing.name AS missingArmorName;
```

### Explanation

- Line 2 defines the pattern "A `Player` wears an `Armor`, which is part of an `ArmorSet`".
- Line 3 introduces the variable `missing` that is necessary for the exclusion "`Player` wears a missing `Armor`" in line 4

> "The WITH clause allows query parts to be chained together, piping the results from one to be used as starting points or criteria in the next." (Taken from [Neo4j developers manual, WITH clauses chapter](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/with/#query-with))

- Line 6 for the identified missing `Armor`s retrieve the `Quest` providing `Npc`s
- Line 7 render the desired output

### Result

```
╒═════════╤═══════════╤══════════════════╕
│"npcName"│"questName"│"missingArmorName"│
╞═════════╪═══════════╪══════════════════╡
│"NPC II" │"Quest II" │"Helmet"          │
├─────────┼───────────┼──────────────────┤
│"NPC I"  │"Quest I"  │"Boots"           │
└─────────┴───────────┴──────────────────┘
```

---

## Extension regarding your comment

If it is important to identify `Armor`s that can be retrieved by `Quest`s only, we have to enhance your model by a label `Monster` with an according relationship `RANDOM_DROPS`.

### Creating your graph

```
CREATE
  (player:Player {name: 'Player'}),
  (shield:Armor {name: 'Shield'}),
  (armor:Armor {name: 'Armor'}),
  (gauntlets:Armor {name: 'Gauntlets'}),
  (boots:Armor {name: 'Boots'}),
  (helmet:Armor {name: 'Helmet'}),
  (dragonSet:ArmorSet {name: 'Dragon Set'}),
  (quest1:Quest {name: 'Quest I'}),
  (quest2:Quest {name: 'Quest II'}),
  (npc1:Npc {name: 'NPC I'}),
  (npc2:Npc {name: 'NPC II'}),
  (monster1:Monster {name: 'Monster I'}),
  (monster2:Monster {name: 'Monster II'}),
  (player)-[:WEARS]->(shield)-[:PART_OF]->(dragonSet),
  (player)-[:WEARS]->(armor)-[:PART_OF]->(dragonSet),
  (player)-[:WEARS]->(gauntlets)-[:PART_OF]->(dragonSet),
  (npc1)-[:PROVIDES]->(quest1)-[:REWARDS]->(boots)-[:PART_OF]->(dragonSet),
  (npc2)-[:PROVIDES]->(quest2)-[:REWARDS]->(helmet)-[:PART_OF]->(dragonSet),
  (monster2)-[:RANDOM_DROPS]->(boots),
  (monster1)-[:RANDOM_DROPS]->(gauntlets),
  (monster1)-[:RANDOM_DROPS]->(shield),
  (monster1)-[:RANDOM_DROPS]->(armor);
```

[image: graph3]

### Solution

```
MATCH
  (player:Player)-[:WEARS]->(armor:Armor)-[:PART_OF]->(dragonSet:ArmorSet),
  (missing)-[:PART_OF]->(dragonSet)
  WHERE NOT (player)-[:WEARS]->(missing:Armor)
WITH DISTINCT missing
MATCH (npc:Npc)-[:PROVIDES]->(quest:Quest)-[:REWARDS]->(missing)
  WHERE NOT (:Monster)-[:RANDOM_DROPS]->(missing)
RETURN npc.name AS npcName, quest.name AS questName, missing.name AS missingArmorName;
```

### Result

```
╒═════════╤═══════════╤══════════════════╕
│"npcName"│"questName"│"missingArmorName"│
╞═════════╪═══════════╪══════════════════╡
│"NPC II" │"Quest II" │"Helmet"          │
└─────────┴───────────┴──────────────────┘
```

Comment: The problem is that in this case I am not sure that the `boots` or `helmet` can be only received as the rewards of quest. They might as well be a random drop from some mob. Or I have just to `match` all possible cases in the query?

Comment: I’ve extended my answer to reflect your "quest only" requirement. Does the answer solve your challenge?

Comment: I kinda get it now. So basically you assume that every quest will definitely have some relation to NPC (in that case) and if there is a quest than you return it. I thought it is possible to infer the relation to NPC by knowing that `quest` node exist. But I don't think in graphs so I am not sure if I should the logic use such logic for graph databases.

Comment: Yes, that's what I went for. If my assumption doesn’t harmonize with your concrete scenario, you could split the last `MATCH` clause in an obligatory part that identifies the `Quest` and an optional part which finds the related `Npc`, if there is one. Just now I have no Neo4j instance at hand unfortunately to verify the Cypher statement, but I think about something like this: 
`MATCH (npc:Npc)-[:PROVIDES]->(quest:Quest), OPTIONAL MATCH (quest)-[:REWARDS]->(missing)`.

Comment: In my case it is probably `optional` match for quests and `optional` for npc.

Answer (score 0):

The [coalesce](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-coalesce) function in Neo4j can be used to compress multiple variables to use the most relevant, non-null value.

```
MATCH (w:Armor)<-[:WEARS]-(p:Player)
MATCH (w)-[:PART_OF]->(set:ArmorSet)
MATCH (missing)-[:PART_OF]->(set)
MATCH (missing)<--(anything)
WHERE NOT (p)-[:WEARS]->(missing)
OPTIONAL MATCH (anything)<-[:GIVES]-(source)
RETURN missing, coalesce(source, anything) as source
```

So in this example, coalesce will return the value of source if their is one, otherwise it will move to the next one and repeat. If all values are null, it will return null.